# interplating 3d matrix by cubic spline

Tags: matlab, spline, cubic

Map provides a 185 x 250 x 3 matrix Map representing an image and “image coordinates” xi and yi. interpolation coordinates 5 < x < 180 and 5 < y < 245, both evenly spaced with spacing 0.1. Interpolate each of the 3 blocks of size 185 x 250 of the matrix Map first in one direction, then the other, to produce a 1751 x 2401 x 3 matrix InterpolatedMap. Set any values larger than 1 to 1, and any less than 0 to 0. Use the image command to compare the original image Map to the image in InterpolatedMap.

I have generated code MyCubicInterpolation which works in following way, xi = linspace(-1,1,150); zi = sin((pi.*xi)/2);

x = linspace(-1,1,200);

y = MyCubicSpline(xi,zi,x);

Now I dont understand my which one will be my 1st direction and which one my second direction, should I select entire block Map(:,:,1) out of three. In short I can not understand next steps.